# How do I use Laravel (5.2) isset with an an href which contains a variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to use `isset()` in my Blade view and, if the value is set, display an `href` which includes the value of a variable.

I am using `{!! !!}` to get it to work but the `{{ }}` inside the URL is being displayed as raw HTML. That's understandable but not what I need.

```
{!! isset($scenario->bpmn) ? '<a href="{{ url($scenario->bpmn) }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' : '' !!}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't nest a `{{ ... }}` or `{!! ... !!}` expression inside another because Blade rewrites them to an output statement similar to the following (simplified) example:

```
echo isset($scenario->bpmn) ? '<a href="{{ url($scenario->bpmn) }}">...</a>' : '';
```

As we can see, Blade doesn't recursively render these output statements. Instead, use string concatenation:

```
{!! isset($scenario->bpmn) ? '<a href="' . url($scenario->bpmn) . '">...</a>' : '' !!}
```

Alternatively, use the `@if` directive, which allows us to include placeholder expressions:

```
@if (isset($scenario->bpmn))
    <a href="{{ url($scenario->bpmn) }}">...</a>
@endif
```

This avoids the use of the unescaped `{!! ... !!}` output which helps to prevent an XSS attack if `$scenario->bpmn` contains user input.

Comment: All good answers but this was exactly what  was after.  Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the only reasonable way to use `@if` directive like so:

```
@if (isset($scenario->bpmn)) 
  <a href="{{ url($scenario->bpmn) }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
@endif
```

It will be also easier to read if you look at file content